# Zend 2 - URL Routing

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I have this URL

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route,array('action'=>
  $action,'week' => $day, 'order_by' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC'));
?>">To day</a>
```

This URL derived all post for current day and this is the URL in navigator.

```
http://localhost/zf2/public/posts/day/2014-07-17/order_by/date/ASC
```

I need to display this URL in my navigator:

```
http://localhost/zf2/public/posts/day/order_by/date/ASC
```

If you have proposition :)

Comment: Please check your `routes.config` and set it up to your liking: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html The provided awnser of @ins0 can push you in the right direction. You will probaly work with segments so you can fill them in.

Answer (score 0):

you may should look at the zf2 documentation and define optional segement types something like

```
posts/day/[:week/][order_by/:order_by/:order]
```

Comment: but I need when I define [/day/] I call [:week/] and I would like not to display the date in the url bar

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide us with the parameter variable, because in your question it is really hard to know what static and dynamic is in your url. So either you should check the MVC.routing documentation or you should provide us with a bit clear example of what can change within your url like Order_by can be ASC or DESC for example.

Comment: as @Kudo says for a detailed answer we need more information about your current config and parameters